# why Xcode do not execute the codes in func tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, snapkit

question:
I set several breakpoints inside the function of tableView. However the Xcode didn't execute the code inside the tableView. please tell me how to fix these.
I'm new to learn about IOS development and I'm trying to write a demo of Tweeter show page. Looking forward for responses!

[image]

Here is code of extension UITablewViewDataSource:

```
extension WechatMomentViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.tweetList?.count ?? 0;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let tweetCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WechatMomentListCell", for: indexPath) as? WechatMomentListCell else {
            fatalError("there is no WechatMomentList")
        }
        
        let tweet = viewModel.tweetList?[indexPath.row]
        
        for i in tweet?.images ?? [] {
            let flagImage = UIImageView()
            flagImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: i.url))
            tweetCell.Images.append(flagImage)
        }
                
        for i in tweet?.comments ?? [] {
            let flagComment = UILabel()
            flagComment.text = "\(i.sender) : \(i.content)"
            tweetCell.comments.append(flagComment)
        }
        tweetCell.senderNick.text = tweet?.sender?.nick
        tweetCell.senderAvatar.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: tweet?.sender?.avatar ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
        tweetCell.content.text = tweet?.content
        
        return tweetCell
    }
}
```

and here is the code of all ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit
import SDWebImage
import Alamofire

//
class WechatMomentViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let viewModel = WechatMomentViewModel()
    var userAvatar = UIImageView()
    var userProfileImage = UIImageView()
    var userNick = UIButton()
    var TweetCell = UITableViewCell()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel.delegate = self
        getUserProfile()
        getTweet()
    }
    
    fileprivate func getUserProfile() {
        viewModel.getUserProfile()
        view.addSubview(userProfileImage)
        userAvatar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        view.addSubview(userAvatar)
        userAvatar.snp.makeConstraints{ (make) in
            make.height.equalTo(80)
            make.width.equalTo(80)
            make.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-10)
            make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        }
        userAvatar.clipsToBounds = true;
        userAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        
        view.addSubview(userNick)
        userNick.snp.makeConstraints{ (make) in
            make.width.equalTo(90)
            make.height.equalTo(20)
            make.trailing.equalTo(userAvatar.snp.leading)
            make.centerY.equalTo(userAvatar)
        }
        
        userProfileImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 414, height: 448)
    }
    
    fileprivate func getTweet() {
        viewModel.getTweet()
    }
}

extension WechatMomentViewController: WechatMomentVCProtocol {
    func refreshUI() {
        if let user = viewModel.user,
           let avatar = user.avatar,
           let profileImage = user.profileImage {
            userAvatar.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: avatar))
            userProfileImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: profileImage))
            userNick.setTitle(user.nick, for: .normal)
        }
    }

}

extension WechatMomentViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.tweetList?.count ?? 0;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let tweetCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WechatMomentListCell", for: indexPath) as? WechatMomentListCell else {
            fatalError("there is no WechatMomentList")
        }
        
        let tweet = viewModel.tweetList?[indexPath.row]
        
        for i in tweet?.images ?? [] {
            let flagImage = UIImageView()
            flagImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: i.url))
            tweetCell.Images.append(flagImage)
        }
                
        for i in tweet?.comments ?? [] {
            let flagComment = UILabel()
            flagComment.text = "\(i.sender) : \(i.content)"
            tweetCell.comments.append(flagComment)
        }
        tweetCell.senderNick.text = tweet?.sender?.nick
        tweetCell.senderAvatar.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: tweet?.sender?.avatar ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
        tweetCell.content.text = tweet?.content
        
        return tweetCell
    }
}
```

and here is identifire code of WechatMomentListCell:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class WechatMomentListCell: UITableViewCell{
    var content = UILabel()
    var senderAvatar = UIImageView()
    var senderNick = UILabel()
    var Images = [UIImageView()]
    var comments = [UILabel()]
    
    
}
```

Comment: Did you assign the data source to the table view?

Comment: nope, I use snapkit instead of storyboard. I thought that should be automatically done.. could you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: tableView.delegate = self , tableView.datasource = self please add this in the viewDidload

Comment: thanks , I tried and got a error of "'datasource' cannot be resolved without a contextual type ""

Comment: `WechatMomentViewController` extends from `UIViewController` and I see no mention of a `UITableView` anywhere in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your class should extend **UITableViewController**  not UIViewController . Also you must register you cell.

```
class WechatMomentViewController: UITableViewController {
    
        let kCellIdentifier = "CellIdentifier"
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            
            self.tableView?.register(WechatMomentListCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier)
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not allowed to use use UITableViewController in Vc in this demo. That's why I have to follow protocol of UITableViewDataSource.

Comment: check snapKit example. hope this helps.. https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit/blob/develop/Example-iOS/ListViewController.swift

Answer (score 1):

Add something like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self // if you are...
    tableView.datasource = self
    ...
}
```

The problem ist that you will most likely (you didn't show) have a regular `UIViewController` and not a `UITableViewController`. Therefore the tableview does not have a delegate nor a datasource. Alternatively, if you are using a storyboard or a xib, you can right click from the tableview to the controller and assign those values there.

Comment: Thanks. But if I add "tableView.datasource = self" , there is a error shows "Reference to member 'datasource' cannot be resolved without a contextual type "

Comment: BTW, I'm using snapkit instead of storyboard.

Comment: I found the problem! It is because I did not have an instance of tableView, and I didn't add it to view. What's more, I need to reloadData.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:
firstly, I don't have TableView(). So I create a new instance of TableView.
Secondly, use

```
view.addSubivew(tableview)
```

Then, member to reloadData from your View Model.

and... try `clean build`(it is really helpful)

Comment: also don't forget to register